# JQuery DataTables How to get selected rows from table when we using paging?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

For example I selected (checked) **2** rows from second page than go to first page and select **3** rows. I want get information from **5** selected rows when I stay at first page.

$('tr.row_selected') - not working

Thanks.

Upd.

I created handler somthing like this:

`$('#example').find('tr td.sel-checkbox').live("click", function () { 
/*code here*/ 
});`

But right now when click event is hadle the row from table is hidding. I think it may be sorting or grouping operation of DataTables. Any idea what I must do with this?

Comment: Please provide code or jsfiddle

Comment: It is default configuration of datatables plugin. Nothing special. I can't find standart function for this operation and can't apply JQuery methods for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#example').find('tr td.sel-checkbox').live("click", function () {
            var data = oTable.fnGetData(this);
            // get key and data value from data object
            var isSelected = $(this).hasClass('row_selected');
            if(isSelected) {
                myCheckValues[key] = value;
                checkedCount++;
            } else {
                delete myCheckValues[key];
                checkedCount--;
            }
        });
```

.....
On submit

```
if(checkedCount > 0) {
            for(var ArrVal in myCheckValues) {
                var values = myCheckValues[ArrVal];   // manipulate with checked rows values data        
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

When a checkbox gets selected, store the row information you want in a global object as a Key-Value pair

I don't remember specifically how i did it before but the syntax was something like

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function()
{
    var row = $(this).parent(); //this or something like it, you want the TR element, it's just a matter of how far up you need to go
    var columns = row.children(); //these are the td elements

    var id = columns[0].val(); //since these are TDs, you may need to go down another element to get to the actual value

    if (!this.checked) //becomes checked (not sure may be the other way around, don't remember when this event will get fired)
    {
        var val1 = columns[1].val();
        var val2 = columns[2].val();

        myCheckValues[id] =[val1,val2]; //Add the data to your global object which should be declared on document ready
    }
    else delete myCheckValues[id];
});
```

When you submit, get the selected rows from your object:

```
for (var i = 0; i < myCheckValues.length; i++)
...
```

Sorry, haven't done JS in a long time so code as is might not work but you get the idea.